# Escape string for Process.Start

Tags: c#, cmd, escaping

How can I escape an unknown string for passing to Process.Start as an argument?

I currently escape basic quotes and backslashes, but recently my input has started to contain things like http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff02/index.htm (Fullwidth quotation mark).

So my question is, what all do I need to escape to safely pass a string as an argument for Process.Start?

**Edit:**
So I need to clarify this. What I really am looking for is a list of all characters that have to be escaped in a quoted string ("foo") for cmd.exe. I originally dealt with double quote character as well as backslash character, but I finally had some input that contained a fullwidth quotation mark (as referenced above) which also needed to be escaped. So the question is, what else do I need to escape for a quoted string argument passed to cmd.exe with Process.Start?

Comment: You may be interested in the [MedallionShell](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell) library, which automatically handles escaping and concatenating process arguments

Answer (score 6):

This might be useful:

> - First, multiple arguments are normally separated from one another by
>     spaces. In Figure 2.3, the command has
>     three arguments, c:*.bak, e:\backup,
>     and /s. Occasionally, other characters
>     are used as argument separators. For
>     example, the COPY command can use +
>     characters to separate multiple
>     filenames.
> - Second, any argument that contains spaces or begins or ends with spaces
>     must be enclosed in double quotes.
>     This is particularly important when
>     using long file and directory names,
>     which frequently contain one or more
>     spaces. If a double-quoted argument
>     itself contains a double quote
>     character, the double quote must be
>     doubled. For example, enter "Quoted"
>     Argument as """Quoted"" Argument".
> - Third, command switches always begin with a slash / character. A
>     switch is an argument that modifies
>     the operation of the command in some
>     way. Occasionally, switches begin with
>     a + or - character. Some switches are
>     global, and affect the command
>     regardless of their position in the
>     argument list. Other switches are
>     local, and affect specific arguments
>     (such as the one immediately preceding
>     the switch).
> - Fourth, all reserved shell characters not in double quotes must
>     be escaped. These characters have
>     special meaning to the Windows NT
>     command shell. The reserved shell
>     characters are:
>
>   & | ( ) < > ^
>
> To pass reserved shell characters as
>   part of an argument for a command,
>   either the entire argument must be
>   enclosed in double quotes, or the
>   reserved character must be escaped.
>   Prefix a reserved character with a
>   carat (^) character to escape it. For
>   example, the following command example
>   will not work as expected, because <
>   and > are reserved shell characters:
>
> ```
>   1. C:\>echo <dir>
>   2. The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
>   Instead, escape the two reserved characters, as follows:
>
>   1. C:\>echo ^<dir^>
>   2. <dir>
> ```
>
> Typically, the reserved shell
>   characters are not used in commands,
>   so collisions that require the use of
>   escapes are rare. They do occur,
>   however. For example, the popular
>   PKZIP program supports a -& switch to
>   enable disk spanning. To use this
>   switch correctly under Windows NT, -^&
>   must be typed.
>
> **Tip**: The carat character is itself a reserved shell character. Thus, to
>   type a carat character as part of a
>   command argument, type two carats
>   instead. Escaping is necessary only
>   when the normal shell interpretation
>   of reserved characters must be
>   bypassed.
>
> - Finally, the maximum allowed length of
>     a shell command appears to be
>     undocumented by Microsoft. Simple
>     testing shows that the Windows NT
>     command shell allows very long
>     commands—in excess of 4,000
>     characters. Practically speaking,
>     there is no significant upper limit to
>     the length of a command.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx

Comment: This helps a bit, but what I'm really looking for is: when in a quoted string, what all needs to be escaped within the quotes.

Comment: As far as I can tell: you only have to escape the fullwidth quotation mark within the fullwidth quotation marks (by doubling them). Step four of the article mentions reserved characters "NOT in double quotes", I assume that you CAN use the characters within the double quotes. And I wouldn't use non-ASCII characters.

Comment: It seems that backslashes should also be escaped by doubling. If two are used in a row, they are interpreted as one; doubling seems to give consistent behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510343/escape-command-line-arguments-in-c/6040946#6040946) is the nearest I've seen to explaining the craziness of Windows command line arguments. It is not as simple as it initially looks.

You shouldn't need to escape U+FF02 in general. The problem is that if you end up passing that character to a command line that doesn't support Unicode, it'll get munged down to its non-compatibility equivalent, the ASCII quote, at which point it becomes dangerous. If your command is going to a tool that doesn't support Unicode, you should fold it down to ASCII *before* applying the argument escaping, rather than letting the tool at the other end do it.

(Usually, the problem will be when that tool uses the C stdlib to read its arguments. This is defined in terms of 8-bit `char`; the Windows stdlib implementation uses the default (“ANSI”) system codepage to encode the string to 8-bit, and that codepage is never a Unicode Transformation Format so you'll always lose characters.)

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at escaping:

```
    public static string QuoteArgument(string arg)
    {
        // The inverse of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx

        // Suppose we wish to get after unquoting: \\share\"some folder"\
        // We should provide: "\\share\\\"some folder\"\\"

        // Escape quotes ==> \\share\\\"some folder\"\
        // For quotes with N preceding backslashes, replace with 2k+1 preceding backslashes.
        var res = new StringBuilder();
        // For sequences of backslashes before quotes:
        // odd ==> 2x+1, even => 2x ==> "\\share\\\"some folder"
        var numBackslashes = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arg.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(arg[i] == '"')
            {
                res.Append('\\', 2 * numBackslashes + 1);
                res.Append('"');
                numBackslashes = 0;
            }
            else if(arg[i] == '\\')
            {
                numBackslashes++;
            }
            else
            {
                res.Append('\\', numBackslashes);
                res.Append(arg[i]);
                numBackslashes = 0;
            }
        }
        res.Append('\\', numBackslashes);

        // Enquote, doubling last sequence of backslashes ==> "\\share\\\"some folder\"\\"
        var numTrailingBackslashes = 0;
        for (var i = res.Length - 1; i > 0; --i)
        {
            if (res[i] != '\\')
            {
                numTrailingBackslashes = res.Length - 1 - i;
                break;
            }
        }
        res.Append('\\', numTrailingBackslashes);

        return '"' + res.ToString() + '"';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how a quote can be present in a google search string:

```
string link = @"https://www.google.com/search?q=\""Hello+World!\""";
Process.Start("CHROME.EXE", link);
```

Comment: The first line of the question specifies that the OP wishes to "escape an **unknown** string". Your provided method cannot be used for such a string.