# How to pass multiple arguments in processStartInfo?

Tags: c#, cmd, netsh, makecert

I want to run some `cmd` command from `c#`code. I followed some blogs and tutorial and got the answer, but I am in little bit confused i.e how should I pass multiple arguments?

I use follow code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = 
...
```

What will be the `startInfo.Arguments` value for the following command line code?

- `makecert -sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=localhost -ir LocalMachine -is Root -ic MyCA.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My MyAdHocTestCert.cer`
- `netsh http add sslcert ipport=127.0.0.1:8085 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF} clientcertnegotiation=enable`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is purely a string:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "-sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=localhost -ir LocalMachine -is Root -ic MyCA.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My MyAdHocTestCert.cer"
```

Of course, when arguments contain whitespaces you'll have to escape them using \" \", like:

```
"... -ss \"My MyAdHocTestCert.cer\""
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.

Comment: And if I need to execute them using the | symbol like in this command? netstat -ano |find /i "listening" |find /i "17328"

Comment: My guess would be to escape  the " by using \", give it a shot.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand this answer, but your code appears to add only one instruction, the first that OP mentioned. How could they add their second instruction with the same startInfo?

Answer (score 6):

Remember to include System.Diagnostics

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myfile.exe");        // exe file
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\..\MyFile\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\"; // exe folder

//here you add your arguments
startInfo.ArgumentList.Add("arg0");       // First argument          
startInfo.ArgumentList.Add("arg2");       // second argument
startInfo.ArgumentList.Add("arg3");       // third argument
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: For space separated arguments, or name/value pairs, this is the best answer. There's a caveat here though. If you need an argument like: `--arg1="value1"`. This will be escaped and won't work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"/c -sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=localhost -ir LocalMachine -is Root -ic MyCA.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My MyAdHocTestCert.cer"
```

use /c as a cmd argument to close cmd.exe once its finish processing your commands

Answer (score 3):

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c \"netsh http add sslcert ipport=127.0.0.1:8085 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF} clientcertnegotiation=enable\"";
```

and...

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c \"makecert -sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=localhost -ir LocalMachine -is Root -ic MyCA.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My MyAdHocTestCert.cer\"";
```

The `/c` tells cmd to quit once the command has completed. Everything after `/c` is the command you want to run (within `cmd`), including all of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

### Just use  "&&" in your command line.

```
 StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C cd C:\Users\yoooo\Desktop && echo This is a sample text file > sample.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

`.NetStandard 2.1` includes a nice feature called `ArgumentList` that automatically escapes arguments for you when given a `Collection<string>`. But (like in my case) if you cannot target `.NetStandard 2.1` you are out of luck...BUT! I dug into the `ProcessStartInfo` [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/PasteArguments.cs) for `.NetStandard 2.1` and was able to extract this class:

```
internal static class PasteArguments {
        internal static void AppendArgument(StringBuilder stringBuilder, string argument) {
            // from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/PasteArguments.cs
            if (stringBuilder.Length != 0) {
                stringBuilder.Append(' ');
            }

            // Parsing rules for non-argv[0] arguments:
            //   - Backslash is a normal character except followed by a quote.
            //   - 2N backslashes followed by a quote ==> N literal backslashes followed by unescaped quote
            //   - 2N+1 backslashes followed by a quote ==> N literal backslashes followed by a literal quote
            //   - Parsing stops at first whitespace outside of quoted region.
            //   - (post 2008 rule): A closing quote followed by another quote ==> literal quote, and parsing remains in quoting mode.
            if (argument.Length != 0 && ContainsNoWhitespaceOrQuotes(argument)) {
                // Simple case - no quoting or changes needed.
                stringBuilder.Append(argument);
            } else {
                stringBuilder.Append(Quote);
                int idx = 0;
                while (idx < argument.Length) {
                    char c = argument[idx++];
                    if (c == Backslash) {
                        int numBackSlash = 1;
                        while (idx < argument.Length && argument[idx] == Backslash) {
                            idx++;
                            numBackSlash++;
                        }

                        if (idx == argument.Length) {
                            // We'll emit an end quote after this so must double the number of backslashes.
                            stringBuilder.Append(Backslash, numBackSlash * 2);
                        } else if (argument[idx] == Quote) {
                            // Backslashes will be followed by a quote. Must double the number of backslashes.
                            stringBuilder.Append(Backslash, numBackSlash * 2 + 1);
                            stringBuilder.Append(Quote);
                            idx++;
                        } else {
                            // Backslash will not be followed by a quote, so emit as normal characters.
                            stringBuilder.Append(Backslash, numBackSlash);
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    if (c == Quote) {
                        // Escape the quote so it appears as a literal. This also guarantees that we won't end up generating a closing quote followed
                        // by another quote (which parses differently pre-2008 vs. post-2008.)
                        stringBuilder.Append(Backslash);
                        stringBuilder.Append(Quote);
                        continue;
                    }

                    stringBuilder.Append(c);
                }

                stringBuilder.Append(Quote);
            }
        }
```

Example Usage:

```
static string GetArgumentStr(List<string> argList) {
        if(argList == null || argList.Count == 0) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var arg in argList) {
            PasteArguments.AppendArgument(sb, arg);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```