# C# Executing CMD command with quotation mark in string

Tags: c#, quotes

I want to execute the following cmd command:

```
"C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe" remove tap0901
```

This is my code in C#:

```
                ProcessStartInfo Install332= new ProcessStartInfo();
                path Install332.FileName = ("cmd.exe");
                //Our cmd code
                Install332.Arguments = (""C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe" remove tap0901"");

                Install332.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Install332.CreateNoWindow = true;

                Process.Start(Install332);
```

But the cmd command won't execute properly since the quotation mark in the cmd command which specifies the "install332.exe" location don't appear. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try by replacing the first and last quotation mark by an apostroph ? Like this : Install332.Arguments = ('"C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe" remove tap0901');
You could also escape the inner apostrophes by adding a \ before ("\"C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe" remove tap0901\"")

Comment: You need to delimit the quotes and the back slashes.  Though why not make the File name the path to install332.exe and then the arguments "remove tap0901" instead?

Comment: Do you have a specific need to launch `cmd.exe` and instruct it to, in turn, launch `install332.exe`?  Otherwise it would simplify things to just launch `install332.exe` directly.  By the way, you probably want your first argument to `cmd.exe` to be `/C` or `/K`, and then subsequent arguments contain the command to execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spaces in file path passed as command line argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598563/spaces-in-file-path-passed-as-command-line-argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
string path = "\"C:\\Program Files\\bin\\install332.exe\" remove tap0901";
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Result should be:

```
"C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe" remove tap0901
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't even bother with "cmd.exe"

```
Install332.FileName = (@"C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe");
Install332.Arguments = ("remove tap0901");
```

This way you don't have to worry about double quotes around the path that has a space in it, but you will need to either delimit the backslashes or use a verbatim string as I have done here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Install332.Arguments = (@"""C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe"" remove tap0901");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have five quotation marks in your given string. Which means one of them doesn't have a match and that is the one extra `"` at the end.

```
Install332.Arguments = (""C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe" remove tap0901");
```

Better use `@` to make your string a [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx), since you are dealing with paths.

> Verbatim string literals start with `@` and are also enclosed in double quotation marks.
>
> The advantage of verbatim strings is that escape sequences are not processed, which makes it easy to write.

```
Install332.Arguments = (@"""C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe"" remove tap0901");
```

Comment: I think you will find that if you want a double quote in a verbatim string literal it still needs doubling up so you would need _@"""C:\Program Files\bin\install332.exe"" remove tap0901"_

Comment: double quotes always have to be delimited either by backslashes in a regular string or by another double quote in a verbatim string.

Comment: Edited my post, my bad.