# How to pass command line argument in a ruby script executing it using C#

Tags: c#, ruby, command-line-arguments

I am executing a ruby script which takes command line arguments using C# code.
`sc.rb` holds the logic of Nessus API integration and yaml file is configuration file which is passed as argument.

Here is what I am currently doing :

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

proc.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
proc.Arguments = @"/c C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\sc.rb --config Nessus.yaml";
```

This code doesn't work for sure.
Is there any way I can specify command line arguments?

Comment: _code doesn't work for sure_ is not very specific. What happens if you run that code? Is there an error? What is the error message?

Comment: It doesn't throw any exception but the script doesn't perform action, because the end result from sc.rb script is a report to be saved at a specific physical location, which is not happening.

Comment: try to use /K instead of /C and see what the output is

Comment: No it didn't help.

Comment: Is this a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061995/4133078

Answer (score 0):

You are using a literal string - e.g. the @ at the beginning but you are then escaping the slashes so it is doubling up the slash. Either omit double \ or the @

e.g.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

proc.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
proc.Arguments = @"/c C:\Users\name\Documents\sc.rb --config Nessus.yaml";
```