# c# pass multiple arguments to ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#

how to execute ProcessStartInfo with multiple arguments?I use this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psexec = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\psexec.exe");
psexec.Arguments = $@"\\{ip} -s cmd /c c:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe";
psexec.Arguments = $@"\\{ip} -s cmd /c c:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe";
Process.Start(psexec);
```

but only the last argument is executed. how do I make everything run in turn?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass multiple arguments in processStartInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061854/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments-in-processstartinfo)

Comment: @MarkusMeyer no

Comment: You are redefining arguments on line 3, instead, try using the ArgumentList property
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.argumentlist?view=net-6.0#system-diagnostics-processstartinfo-argumentlist

Comment: @SithLee ProcessStartInfo does not contain the ArgumentList property

Comment: @zaknafein I see you must be using .net framework then, you can just use the '&' separator between commands to run one command after the other.

Comment: Why are you using `psexec` to run `cmd` to run `wmic`, why not just run `wmic` directly from `psexec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using .net core you can access the ArugmentList property.
If not you can separate the commands with the '&' separator.

For instance, in the command prompt, you can run 2 commands like

```
start notepad.exe & echo hello
```