# CMD is confused with quotation marks (") using c# process

Tags: c#, cmd, process

What I have is a command which is delivered to the cmd to be executed.

```
string command = @"C:\Privat\Docs\programm.exe" + " " + "-k" + " " + "https://thisIsAnUrl/DoIt=" + argument;
```

The argument has to look like this:    `\"xx:xx:xx:xx\"`

When I execute it with this command, I'll get the output
`C:\Privat\Docs\programm.exe -k https://thisIsAnUrl/DoIt=\"xx:xx:xx:xx\"`
which is working like I intend it to be.

The problem is: when the directory contains a space (`C:\Privat\Do cs\programm.exe`) you would need to add quotation marks to the directory:

```
string command = @"""C:\Privat\Do cs\programm.exe""" + " " + "-k" + " " + "https://thisIsAnUrl/DoIt=" + argument;
```

The output then become `"C:\Privat\Do cs\programm.exe" -k https://thisIsAnUrl/DoIt=\"xx:xx:xx:xx\"` which is working fine if I execute it directly in the cmd, but if I call the cmd via c# with this code I get an error that the command was either false written or not found (although it is correct and when i copy exactly this output and, like I said, execute it directly with cmd it is working fine).

What the cmd confuses are the \"  before and after xx:xx:xx:xx but it is essential for the command to leave them

What am I missing? Please help

Comment: "I get an error that the command was either false written or not found" - could you post the code and exact error message?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The exact Error Message (on german): Der Befehl ___ ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden      which translates to: The command ___ was either fasle written or could not be found                           and the code is irrelevant here it is really just the \" in the end that's the problem

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for correcting my writing and form mistakes in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to escape the quotes by adding `^` before of the characters you want/have to escape as described in the link below.

see more: [Escape double quotes in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/escape-double-quotes-in-parameter)

**UPDATE**

Just try it directly before the backslash `\`, that you assume to produce the problem, therefore somehow like this: `^\"xx:xx:xx:xx^\"`. If this won't work, try to also escape the double quotes like this: `^\^"xx:xx:xx:xx^\^"`. Or the third option: Just escape the double quotes: `\^"xx:xx:xx:xx\^"`

**UPDATE 2**

Since this is accepted in the comments, do the following: Make your code look like this:

`+ " " + "\"https://thisIsAnUrl/DoIt=\"" + argument;`

Comment: I see what you mean, but I have actually no clue where to put the ^

Comment: thanks a lot for me it works like this "^\\^\"xx:xx:xx:xx^\\^\"" , but now my new problem is: the directory I am heading to contains empty spaces let's say: C:\Privat\Do cs\programm.exe           I wrote it like this   @"""C:\Privat\Do cs\programm.exe"""     but the cmd response with (translated from german): >the command "C:\Privat\Do" is either wrong written or could not be found<    Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the cmd doesn't interpret your path as a complete string, so there have to be quotation marks `"` around the string. Try with one more or with an additional single quotation mark before and behind. If my answer solved your originally posted question, please mark it so.

Comment: The original problem is/are the spaces in the directory path (sorry if I didn't point that out clearly)                              I added another pair of quoation marks before and after the path, but the cmd gives me still the same error (false writen or not found)

Comment: As I told you in the last comment, try with single quotiation marks on both sides.  -> Instead of having 3 double quotes in your string, it should look something like that: `@"'C:\Privat\Do cs\programm.exe'"`

Comment: Already tried that. The cmd responses with the error >Der angegebene Pfadname ist ungültig< which translates to >The given (directory) path is invalid< I also tried it with `@'"C:\Privat\Do cs\programm.exe"'`

Comment: My last hope... To make it look like this: `@"C:\Privat\Do cs\programm.exe"` try this in your code: `+ " " + "\"https://thisIsAnUrl/DoIt=\"" + argument;`

Comment: You're welcome. I included the solution in the answer. Don't forget to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just need to set both the `Filename` and `Arguments` properties separately when invoking the new process.

Here's some C# code I am using to execute cmd.exe (notice the `/c` parameter being used here and additional surrounding quotes).

```
string cmd7z = @"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe";
string filename = "filetodecompress.bz2";

var processDecompress = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = $"/c \"\"{cmd7z}\" e -so \"{filename}\"\""
    }
};

processDecompress.Start();
processDecompress.WaitForExit();
int returnCode = processDecompress.ExitCode;
```

Comment: @Shmosi If you mean my code sample, I just edited my answer and added a missing trailing quote from the Arguments string. I cut and paste and it compiles

Comment: Otherwise, my guess would be that you don't need to add the back bracket (escaped) quote mark `\"` within your parameter i.e. it should be `C:\Privat\Docs\programm.exe -k https://thisIsAnUrl/DoIt="xx:xx:xx:xx"`

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040946/770763) about escaping command line arguments in c# might solve your problem.

It contains detailed explanation and some examples on how .NET handles escape sequences for command line args.