# Pass a path with space as an argument

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm running some code in C# where I call a batch file, and I need to pass a Path with space as an argument and it does not work.

I have tried to call my argument different ways in the batch %1 , %~1, "%1", '%1'. None of these work. Also in my C# code I tried to convert it to string and it wont work either

C# code.

```
string argument =   textBox10.Text.ToString()  ; 
string command = @"/c powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted X:\PathToBatch\Run.bat" + " " + argument;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", command);
```

Batch code :

```
echo %1
Pause
```

When I pass an argument C:\Program Files\Test as a directory, it prints "C:\Program" and stops at the space. 
How can I get the full path ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have to use Quotes like this `+ " """ + argument + """";` Did not actually tested this. Just for explanation.

Comment: what happens when you do `echo "%*"`

Comment: when I go %* it shows everything but the fact is that I have 6 arg, so I might not be able to use that. Im my command line it looks like that :
@"/c powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted X:\PathToBatch\Run.bat" + " " + arg1 + " " + arg2 + " " + arg3

Comment: I already tried to use quotes too yeah

Comment: you should pass your arguments quoted from `C#` code

Comment: The solution can vary based on what command you want to execute, so please make your question more clear and exact.

Comment: Yes, I know, I am showing you your problem. `cmd` works on next command based on spaces, so you would need to let it know which stdin is which position.. i.e. `echo %~1 %~2` and run it as `batchfile.cmd "c:\program files" stdin2` compared to `batchfile.cmd c:\program files stdin2` (which now has 3 args)

Comment: Why do you use powershell and not run the batch file directly? Introducing powershell as a middleman makes matters more complicated

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
string command = @"/c powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted X:\PathToBatch\Run.bat"+ " \""+ argument +"\" ";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", command);
```

This will "write" the following line in your console :

```
/c powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted X:\PathToBatch\Run.bat "C:\Program Files\Test"
```

Comment: Are still you having the same issue with only "C:\Program" being printed ?

Comment: Yes, also when I have several args the next ones take the value 'Files\Test'

Comment: I'm not a batch expert but by looking on the web the only thing that could cause this to happend is to forget the double quotes on the command line.
Try to write it manually in the cmd like so :
`/c powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted X:\PathToBatch\Run.bat "C:\Program Files\Test"`
If you still have the same results then there is something wrong with batch. (or with me but in any case i don't think i can help you anymore atm )

Answer (score 0):

pass your argument double quoted, like so: `"C:\Program Files\Test"`.

the issue is that your argument contains a space so it treated as two different arguments

Comment: @Le Pain, purposed a solution for your code. my point is if you want to pass one argument which contains spaces then you must quote it, so the shell will also treat it as one argument

Comment: still have the same issue even when it is quoted

Comment: @RhonYz check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510343/escape-command-line-arguments-in-c-sharp it might help you

Answer (score 0):

It worked with simples quotes " '" + arg + "' ", and by calling it in the batch as %~1